# is it possible to show the kubernetes image pull progress

Tags: kubernetes

When I roll update the kubernetes deployment, the pod status stuck on pending status for 3 minites(the image should spent less than 1 minites to pull), then I using this command to show the pod status:

```
➜  retire git:(gateway) kubectl describe pod dolphin-post-service-6d8b4fd8b4-nl4kd -n reddwarf-pro
Name:           dolphin-post-service-6d8b4fd8b4-nl4kd
Namespace:      reddwarf-pro
Priority:       0
Node:           k8smasterone/172.29.217.209
Start Time:     Wed, 10 Aug 2022 00:33:23 +0800
Labels:         app=dolphin-post-service
                pod-template-hash=6d8b4fd8b4
Annotations:    cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: fb54cff6a7fa39419f3249f89e8fd9e41768182bb3917aef0183452ff331789c
                cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.97.196.243/32
                cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.97.196.243/32
                kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2022-07-22T14:49:57Z
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/dolphin-post-service-6d8b4fd8b4
Containers:
  dolphin-post-service:
    Container ID:
    Image:          registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:cc5cd79c4aa5bf9f0a2aba0c9a775be7e6d3d469
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     1500M
      memory:  600Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      200m
      memory:   256Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:11014/actuator/health/liveness delay=190s timeout=30s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:11014/actuator/health delay=160s timeout=30s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      APOLLO_META:  <set to the key 'apollo.meta' of config map 'pro-apollo-config'>  Optional: false
      ENV:          <set to the key 'env' of config map 'pro-apollo-config'>          Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /root/data from dolphin-post-service-persistent-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-l6m2z (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  dolphin-post-service-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  dolphin-post-service-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-l6m2z:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  3m53s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post-service-6d8b4fd8b4-nl4kd to k8smasterone
  Normal  Pulling    3m52s  kubelet            Pulling image "registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:cc5cd79c4aa5bf9f0a2aba0c9a775be7e6d3d469"
```

the pod status shows that the image was pull right now, it seems never complete. why did this happen? what should I do to fix it? BTW, the log could not access, shows error like this:

```
Failed to load logs: container "dolphin-post-service" in pod "dolphin-post-service-6d8b4fd8b4-nl4kd" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
Reason: BadRequest (400)
```

Comment: have you checked logs for any indications ?

Comment: the logs could not accessed, shows container creating... @P....

Comment: I meant, on your `k8smasterone` node, run `sudo crictl image list`  command and check if the image is present or not ? also note the size

Comment: then check `sudo crictl inspecti  <image-id>`